# Change timezone for logging

Tags: logs, time, timezone

On a new server, I've changed timezone from UTC to my local timezone, Europe/London:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London /etc/localtime
```

That gives me the desired time when, for example, I run `date`. However, new items in log files (e.g. `/var/log/secure`) are timestamped with the 'old' timezone, which is an hour off (worse, they don't even indicate timezone, but that's a whole other issue!).

I haven't restarted anything since I changed `/etc/localtime`; does everything require a reboot to get in sync, or is there an appropriate daemon I can ping in order to refresh the timezone?

Comment: Reboot, or restart each daemon so that they pick up on the change.

Answer (score 2):

Most services are using syslog and it would be enough to restart syslog or respective rsyslog.
For example at Debian

```
service rsyslog restart
```